# RefreshApex not pulling updated apex query results

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

Running into an issue where RefreshApex isn't working as expected due to a timing issue.

I have an abstracted SOSL query pulling records of two sObject types, and returning whichever was updated most recently. The information from each record is pulled into a wrapper, parsed into JSON, and sent into the LWC. This is working as expected.

Where it goes off the rails is when I submit new records and the two sObjects should be updated, thereby displaying the newly created sObject. This works correctly after a few refreshes of the page, but obviously I would like to prevent the user from having to sit and refresh until the appropriate record appears.

Here is the relevant JS file:

```javascript
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getJSON from '@salesforce/apex/CLASS.getJSON';

export default class CLASS extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track validationRecord;
    _wiredJSON;
    error;
    loaded = false;

    get validationRecordExists() {
        return this.validationRecord != null;
    }


    @wire(getJSON, { recordId: '$recordId' })
    retrieveJSON(value){
        console.log('wire call');
        this._wiredJSON = value;
        const { data, error } = value;   
        if(data){
            console.log("jsonDATA", data)
            this.validationRecord = data;
        } else if(error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
        this.loaded = true;
    }

    handleRefresh() {
        alert('refreshing...');
        this.loaded = false;
        refreshApex(this._wiredJSON)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('refreshsuccesss');
                this.loaded = true;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('refreshapexerror', error);
            });
    }
}
```

I have updated my `@wire` call based on other similar posts, and in theory it is working correctly per my log statements, but it is not displaying the values as expected. My Apex class is marked as `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)`:

```apex
public with sharing class CLASS {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getJSON(String recordId) {
        return CLASS.wrapData(recordId) == null ? null : JSON.serialize(CLASS.wrapData(recordId));
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are the new record(s) being created by the mentioned component? If you have a custom method for creating records, `handleRefresh()` should be called when new record is being created.

Comment: @Raul handleRefresh() is being called by a child component creating the new record that is bubbling up to the parent, which is pulling the records.

Comment: Ah I see, wasn't super clear from the code above. I assume you send a custom event from child to parent, then parent's event handler calls `handleRefresh()`? Do you see the alert message in that scenario but UI still doesn't refreshes listing newly created record?

Comment: Correct. Event bubbles from child to parent, and then parent's event handler calls handleRefresh(). Alert is showing, logs are showing, newly created record is not showing in the UI.

Comment: Looks like you have implemented it correctly and this is weird. Only thing I can think of is if by any chance you have caching enabled on your org? If not then, try again after [disabling caching setting during development](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/debug_disable_caching.htm)

Comment: Darn, that doesn't seem to work either. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: In the child component, are you waiting for the create transaction to complete? If you weren't waiting, it would be easy for the `refreshApex()` method to fire before the backend has finished creating your records.

Comment: Good call, let me check it!

Comment: My child component is using imperative Apex with a .then().catch() block, so it should be good there.

Comment: Embarrassing though it is to admit... there are times when I've put in a timeout around the target method call to handle situations like this. Last resort only though.

Comment: Kindly try removing the cacheable true once and check Evelyn

Comment: @CasparHarmer I tried that too, and it was unfortunately just as inconsistent!

Comment: @JPM the cacheable=true is necessary for the component, but I have tried and it doesn't pull any information at all when it is removed.

Comment: how are the records queried for WrapData return value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure out a workaround after coming back to this several months later. Played around with it, and `refreshApex(this._wiredJSON)` wasn't working, as evidenced by lack of `console.log` statements within the `retrieveJSON` function, although the `refreshsuccess` log was showing.

Instead of using `refreshApex()`, I opted to have the JSON from the created record bubble up to the parent.